# Difference between two ZonedDateTime in Period

Tags: date, java-8, java-time, period

Using LocalDate, I got the difference expressed in a Period instance. For example:

```
LocalDate born = LocalDate.of(1990, Month.SEPTEMBER, 30);
Period myAge = Period.between(born, LocalDate.now());
System.out.println("My age is: "+myAge.getYears()+" years "+myAge.getMonths()+" months "+myAge.getDays()+" days.");
```

Output:

> My age is: 26 years 6 months 23 days

So, I was using period to get the age in years, months and days.

I would like to do the same with ZoneDateTime using two time zones (US/Pacific and Australia/Melbourne). For example:

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(); // US/Pacific

LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(1990, Month.SEPTEMBER, 30);
LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(23, 55);
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Australia/Melbourne");
ZonedDateTime born = ZonedDateTime.of(date, time, zone);
```

I would like to get the same output as I got with LocalDate. What should I do? Does it make sense?

Expected output:

> My age is: 26 years 6 months 24 days

Comment: The issue is you will need to decide things like rounding of hours to days, and in which time zone to count; because of different DST rules, the counts in the two zones may not agree.

Answer (score 4):

The first line of [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) documentation state that it is a date based amount of time in ISO-8601 format. It is not meant to be used with XXXTime.

However, [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) offer you an [`until`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#until-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) method which will return the number of a given [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) until another [`Temporal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/Temporal.html) (`now` in your case).

For example :

```
born.until(now, ChronoUnit.YEARS);
```

would return 26.

One trick is to add the difference retrieved to the starting date and then process the next `ChronoUnit`

For example :

```
long years = born.until(now, ChronoUnit.YEARS);
born = born.plusYears(years);

long months = born.until(now, ChronoUnit.MONTHS);
born = born.plusMonths(months);

long days = born.until(now, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
```

And then you can print your variables.

Comment: @JodaStephen This is why I reassign the born variable with plusYears and plusMonths right after the check.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using a `ZonedDateTime` for a birth date, I'd recommend storing a `LocalDate` and a `ZoneId` (ie. in separate fields/columns).

The simple answer to getting the `Period` from two `LocalDate` instances is to call `toLocalDate()` on both. As you'll realise, there is the problem that those `ZonedDateTime` instances might be in different time-zones, which might require work to normalize. But again, I'd stress that the better storage for this data is two fields - `LocalDate` and a `ZoneId`.

```
Period p = Period.between(born.toLocalDate(), now.toLocalDate());
// warning! the above ignores time-zones, assuming both are the same
```

If you need the difference between the two in `Period` plus `Duration` (for the remaining seconds), you can use this:

```
Period p = Period.between(born.toLocalDate(), now.toLocalDate());
Duration d = Duration.between(born.with(now.toLocalDate()), now);
```

The final option is to use [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/). The soon to be released v1.1 will contain a class `PeriodDuration` that combines a `Period` and a `Duration` and allows the amount of time between two `LocalDateTime` instances to be stored.

Answer (score 0):

The **primary** reason you should use `LocalDate` to represent birthday is because everyone observes their birthday the same way, or put another way, everyone observes their birthday using the clock according to where they are currently at. If you were born in France, and right now are living in the US which has a different timezone offset, you wouldn't celebrate your birthday by observing France's current date, you would instead check the date where you are currently which is *local* to you. Temporal classes with timezone support should be used for events that span regions, for example, flight arrivals and departures tracking software. So using `ZonedDateTime` to describe birthday is not wrong, it is semantically incorrect.

Also, `Period` implements `TemporalAmount` which obviously represents a span of time. So using it to represent birthday is (again) not wrong, but it makes your intention less clear. Birthday is an exact moment on the timeline, not a duration, so all in all, `LocalDate` is the best choice